# Hive does not MapJoin a small table against the Union of two large tables

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 3 small tables: `smallTable0`, `smallTable1`, and `smallTable3`. They all have fewer than 100 rows and identical schemas. I also have 3 large tables: `largeTable0`, `largeTable1`, and `largeTable3`. The all have more than 1M rows, have identical schemas, share the `id` column with the small tables, are are partitioned on something other than `id` (in case partitioning matters, I suspect it does not).

After setting `hive.auto.convert.join=true`, the following cases result in a MapJoin, as expected:

- Joining `smallTable0` against `smallTable1`
- Joining `smallTable0` against `largeTable0`
- Joining `smallTable0` against the `smallTable1 UNION ALL smallTable2`

The following cases do not result in a MapJoin, as expected:

- Joining `largeTable0` against anything.
- Joining `smallTable0` against anything with `hive.auto.convert.join=false`

Unexpectedly however, the following case also does not result in a MapJoin:

- Joining `smallTable0` against `largeTable0 UNION ALL largeTable1`

The exact query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM smallTable0 s
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM largeTable0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM largeTable1 
  ) x
) l
  ON s.id = l.id;
```

It runs fine, but with a Common Join instead of a MapJoin and it is causing a performance hit. Creating a view which represents `largeTable0 UNION ALL largeTable1` does not resolve the issue. I'm sure creating a table which is `largetTable0 UNION ALL largeTable1` would resolve the issue, but duplicating so much data and then keeping them in sync is undesirable.

The source code for the Union operator ([here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/398c9c6737b905cf1ae64b9bc52b8f919879bd82/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/UnionOperator.java)) has a comment which I find somewhat cryptic.

```
/**
* Union operators are not allowed either before or after a explicit mapjoin hint.
* Note that, the same query would just work without the mapjoin hint (by setting
* hive.auto.convert.join to true).
**/
@Override
public boolean opAllowedBeforeMapJoin() {
  return false;
}

@Override
public boolean opAllowedAfterMapJoin() {
  return false;
}
```

It seems to suggest that the UNION operator is not allowed with an explicit MapJoin hint, but that the UNION operator is allowed with MapJoins initiated as a result of `hive.auto.convert.join`. However I do not understand why one would be allowed the other disallowed. Unless "just work" means that the query will "work", just not with a MapJoin. If this were the case, however, I would have expected joining `smallTable0` to `smallTable1 UNION ALL smallTable2` to result in a Common Join.

Is the odd behavior a result of a bug in Hive, a bug in my code, a missing feature in Hive, or a misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify hints to Hive for handling the tables during a join. I always specify **MAPJOIN** or **STREAMTABLE** if I know if a small table is candidate for join, or the very large table that should be streamed to the others.

e.g.

```
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(smalltable0) */ * FROM smallTable0 s
```